# I've tried to get this regex replacement to work in the chrome snippets replacement panel `/((m|n))0/ ` but couldn't figure it out

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-devtools

Here's the snippet:

```
//Get userId,questionId and title 
  let btn0 = document.createElement('input');
  btn0.type = "button";
  btn0.value = 'Read Content';
  btn0.onclick = () => {
  console.clear();
  let b = [["Item","String"]];
  let c = document.querySelectorAll('div#un1')[0].children;
  let a = Array.from(c);
  a.forEach((e , i) => {
    b.push([i + 1,e.innerText]);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("test",JSON.stringify(b));  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(b)); 
  }
  if(m0)m0.prepend(btn0);
```

I was just trying to replace btn0 to btn1 and m0 to m1 to start another snippet without rewriting all of common stuff.  I ended up using something I wrote but would like to be able to use the builtin tool in Chrome dev tools.

I was hoping one of you knows how to use the replacement tool on Chrome Dev Tools better than I.

Comment: Maybe `/(m|n)0/g` and `$1\1`?

Comment: I though I'd need a set of capturing parenthesis

Comment: That's not working for me

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions. If you'd like to add your own answer, you're free to do so, giving appropriate credit to the original author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the regex engine used in Chrome snippets is still JavaScript `RegExp`, but replacing functionality is not the regular one.

There are two approaches here:

1. Use a  lookbehind: `(?<=m|n)0` => `1`
2. Use a named capturing group: `(?<name>m|n)0` => `$<name>1`

Do not forget to click the `.*` icon to enable regular expression replace mode!

Comment: I have not been able to find a way to get anything to work on the Chrome Source Panel Replace.  I guess I'll just get use to moving it to my own tool.

Comment: @Cooper I tested these two solutions in my Snippets window and both worked.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your usage notes at first.  It took some more trial and error to figure them out.  Now I finally see the positive results thank you.  I figured you either knew they worked or tried them yourself.  But I wasn't implementing them correctly. I really appreciate your assistance.  Thank You.